# why use production over development for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel

Are there any major differences between the two?  I have yet to see a doc that explains what the major difference is?  Performance??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are significant differences between "development" and "production" modes of operation even if the two seem superficially similar.

In development mode any file in `app/` and `config/routes.rb` is reloaded with each request. This can take a considerable amount of time to process, but has the advantage of producing an up-to-date response based on any changes to your code-base, something that is presumably on-going in a development environment. Since the production environment should not change between deployments, Rails will cache your controllers, views, routes, helpers and models for maximum performance. Any changes to the source will require an application restart.

Another feature of development is that the Rails logging level is set to `debug` which is as verbose as possible. Not only do you get a detailed breakdown of every SQL call made, but you also get minor warnings and other informative messages that would otherwise be omitted in production. This logging is a considerable drag on performance and should not be used in a production environment unless you're trying to diagnose a problem. These log files get very big very quickly and it can be difficult to rotate them without restarting your web server processes.

There is also a method in the development environment to rescue from exceptions and render them as a human-readable error report. This is useful for debugging, but in a production environment may expose sensitive details about your application as it often includes a lot of information about the filesystem, key parameters, and so on. This should never be enabled on a production site.

These differences may not be obvious, but you simply need to compare the configuration settings in `config/environments/development.rb` and `config/environments/production.rb`. Unfortunately it is not obvious what some of the defaults are, as they are not expressed clearly in these files sometimes, but the basics are usually there.

Comment: Perfect!  Now if I wanted to turn on the debug mode WHILE on production, can I still set it to DEBUG?

Comment: You can adjust the logging level in `production.rb` but be careful to turn it off after you're done. It's not uncommon for it to grow at multiple GB per hour.

Answer (score 5):

In Rails production environment, your app code is cached, so the interpreter doesn't have to reload your classes every time it calls a method.  Your app is basically stored in memory. This gives definite speed improvements.

Also, it does a lot less logging by default; for example, production logs don't contain every single sql call like your development logs do.

Answer (score 2):

Caching & error handling.

Comment: With caching, is there a substantial performance increase? Lets say my pages are not static, but rather very much dynamic in a sense, would this still be beneficial?

Comment: All the application code will be cached between requests, so they don't have to be parsed on each request. This is why you can make changes to a file and get instant changes in the development environment but not in the production. Load the application in both environments and compare the web brick output for identical requests, you will see the difference in execution time.